# In enzyme cannot update state using instance().state and update()

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my React Component using enzyme. The component has this render method:

```
render() {
        let modal = null;
        let modalTitle = this.state.isEditing ? 'Edit Event' : 'Add Event';
        if (this.state.showModal) {
            modal = (<div className="event-modal">
                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal}>
                   ...
                 </Modal>
            </div>);
        }
        return (
            <div style={{height: '500px', width: '1000px'}}>
                <BigCalendar
                    events={this.props.events}
                    startAccessor='startDate'
                    endAccessor='endDate'
                    onSelectSlot={this.onDayClick}
                    selectable={true}
                    onSelectEvent={this.onEventClick}
                />
                {modal}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In my test case I want to verify that the modal is displayed when showModal = true, and enzyme recommends you use instance() to get your component in the correct state for detailed tests so I tried using instance() and then update(), but it did not work. My test case that ended up working was using setState(), which enzyme recommends against using if possible. This is my test case:

```
it('render should display modal if showModal is true', () => {
        const calendar = shallow(<CalendarPres events={[]}/>);
        //The commented out code does not work, but I'm not sure why
        //calendar.instance().state.showModal = true;
        //calendar.update();
        calendar.setState({showModal: true});
        expect(calendar.find('.event-modal').exists()).toBe(true);
    });
```

setState() works, but using instance() and then update() does not. Why does update() not re-render my component properly?

Comment: The enzyme documentation for setState(), where they recommend you use instance():
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md

The enzyme documentation for instance: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html

Comment: Thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enzyme recommends that as you said, but this would not be so good

```
 calendar.instance().state.showModal = true;
```

since the only case when we should set the state directly would be in the component constructor.

We should always use `setState()` that works asynchronously when setting the state.

---

From [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html): [1](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) and [2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

---

The `update()` method will only work if there is something to update. Looks like the state hasn't been changed at the moment `update()` fires.

Comment: Thanks, I thought when enzyme was saying use instance() to setup the state they meant directly and that they could hook into the Component somehow to make it work. I will use setState() in the future.